# Resolve a path name with .. parent directory specifiers ("dot dot") without resolving symlinks

Tags: java, file, filesystems, guava, apache-commons

Given a path like `/a/./b/c/../d`, I would like to remove all the "current directory" indicators (i.e., period) and "parent directory" indicators (i.e., ..), giving `a/b/d`.

I could use `File.getCanonicalPath()`, but that also resolves symlinks, which I don't want.

Any simple way?  That is, simpler than writing a tokenizer and handling it all myself.

Bonus points if you can tell me what the right name for '.' and '..' are in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FilenameUtils.normalize()` in the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library - [see javadoc here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#normalize-java.lang.String-boolean-).

"Dot" (`.`) is the current directory and "dot dot" (`..`) is the parent directory - [read up on unix directories](http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/ITS/training/unix/unix1.html).

Comment: `getAbsolutePath` doesn't resolve `.` or `..` - it only ensures a path is absolute.  Paths with `..` can still be absolute, as in my example.

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify I am well-aware what `.` and `..` are.  what I meant was what to _call_ the dot forms of these specifically, as in the title to my question.

Comment: Ha, then "dot" and "dot dot" :)

Comment: @AnandRockzz If you want that `~` to work, then use something crude like this: `filePath = badFilePath.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("~"), System.getProperty("user.home"));`

Answer (score 13):

Guava also has this as [`Files.simplifyPath(String)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#simplifyPath-java.lang.String-). Your best bet, though, (if you can use JDK7) is to represent your path as a [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and use [`Path.normalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize%28%29) to get the normalized version.

Comment: Thanks.  This is actually very useful for me as we depend on guava but not commons-io currently.  Not at Java 7, but the link was very informative.  I hadn't thought about the case of a/../b where a is a symlink.

Answer (score 2):

Have also a look at this question (Java 7 or newer):
[Java: how to normalize paths with nio Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28053779/91497)

The solution is great, but it is not portable (it will not work on Windows machines).

Answer (score 0):

[Path.normalize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize()) does what you're looking for, and does not require any third party. It is available since jdk8.

```
Paths.get("/a/./b/c/../d").normalize()
=> /a/b/d
```

Be careful, however, that it will resolve the path according to the current OS. Executing the same command on Windows yields a different result.

```
Paths.get("/a/./b/c/../d").normalize()
=> \a\b\d
```